# Every time i open an existing indexed db(via pouchdb), small amount of data(188 or 161 bytes) is appended to my offline storage data in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb, pouchdb

I'm trying to open an existing pouchdb database according to [official documents](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_database) as:

```
var db = new PouchDB('table_db');
```

and also i'm checking google chrome offline storage each time i open the 'table_db' as:

```
navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota (

   function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {
      console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
   },
   function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  }
);
```

and what i get after multiple refreshes is:

```
we are using  26234  of  2629807161 bytes
we are using  26422  of  2629806901 bytes
we are using  26610  of  2629806926 bytes
...
```

My adapter is 'indexeddb' and i'm using chrome as my target browser.
it may exceed the limitation i fear, what can i do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backing store for the Indexed DB implementation in Chrome is [leveldb](https://github.com/google/leveldb), which allows for high data throughput by appending data to a log and then occasionally compacting the data to various table files and eliminating old data. Each access does write a minimal amount of data to the log, which is what you're seeing. At some point the compaction algorithm will kick in and reclaim the unused space.